# Перевести строки из txt в json

Tags: регулярные-выражения, json

Здравствуйте. Как перевести файл txt вида

```
area_id = 0 city_id = 36 place_id = 14 Павлино
area_id = 0 city_id = 2 Бронницы
area_id = 3 Волоколамский район
```

в json файл вида

```
{
    "Павлино": [{
            "area_id": 0
        },
        {
            "city_id": 36
        },
        {
            "place_id": 14
        }
    ],
    "Бронницы": [{
            "area_id": 0
        },
        {
            "city_id": 2
        }
    ],
    "Волоколамский район": [{
        "area_id": 3
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Да простят меня все, кто это видел.

https://regex101.com/r/VT7mXB/1

Регулярное выражение:

```
(?(?<=\A)(?=[\s\S]*(\{)))^(?=.*=\s*\d+\s+(.*$))(?=[\s\S]*(")(:),(\[))\s*|\G(\w+)\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*(?=[\s\S]*(\{)(\})(")(:)(,))|\G.+$(?!\Z)(?=[\s\S]*(,)\[(\]))|\n.*(\}).*\Z
```

Флаги:

```
mX
```

Исходный текст должен быть немного изменён (в его конец надо дописать литералы):

```
area_id = 0 city_id = 36 place_id = 14 Павлино
area_id = 0 city_id = 2 Бронницы
area_id = 3 Волоколамский район
{}":,[]
```

Строка замены:

```
$1$3$2$3$4$5$8$10$6$10$11$7$9$12$14$13$15
```

Результат (абсолютно валидный JSON с крайней запятой):

```
{"Павлино":[{"area_id":0},{"city_id":36},{"place_id":14},],
"Бронницы":[{"area_id":0},{"city_id":2},],
"Волоколамский район":[{"area_id":3},],}
```

Задание для самостоятельного решения:

Сделать формирование результата пробелами и переносами строк.

Comment: Половину не понял, но выглядит красиво, даже завораживающе xDD

Answer (score 0):

Да простят меня те, кто предложит нормальный вариант.
Я бы разбил эту задачу на 2 задачи (точнее регекспа), `area` - ищет все кириллические словосочетания, `data` - все остальные данные (грубо говоря). Дальше уже надо логику на нужный язык перекладывать и если надо, то превращать объект в json.

**Вариант на JS:**

```js
let obj = {}, j = -1;
const str = `
    area_id = 0 city_id = 36 place_id = 14 Павлино
    area_id = 0 city_id = 2 Бронницы
    area_id = 3 Волоколамский район
  `,
  area = str.match(/(?! )[а-яё ]+/gi), // Находим в нашем тексте все элементы начинающиеся не с пробела и имеющие в себе кириллические символы с пробелами
  data = str.match(/([\w]+)/gi); // Находим в нашем тексте все "Буквенный или цифровой символ или знак подчёркивания"
      
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
  let dataObj = {};

  if(data[i] === 'area_id') { // Так как мы знаем, что все данные нужные нам начинаются со значения area_id, то возьмем его за основу построения нового объекта
    ++j;
    obj[area[j]] = [];
  }

  dataObj[data[i]] = data[i + 1]; // Не очень понимаю зачем разбивать параметры на подобъекты, но так по задаче

  obj[area[j]].push(dataObj); // Какая-то магия
}

console.log(obj);
```

RegExp который ищет всю нужную информацию выглядел бы так:

```
/([\w]+)|((?! )[а-яё ]+)/gi
```

, но я не придумал как с ним работать без новых регекспов.